# need to list all friends with facebook.py

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i use facebook.py from:
https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

my problem is:
I don't know to use the next-url from graph.get_object("me/friends")

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends")
```

Comment: This is a really good tool to mess with and learn Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 4):

If you type in `/me/friends` into the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends), you'll see that it returns a JSON file, which is just a combination of dictionaries and lists inside one another.

For example, the output could be:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Foo", 
      "id": "1"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Bar", 
      "id": "1"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "some_link"
  }
}
```

This JSON file is already converted to a Python dictionary/list. In the outer dictionary, the key `data` maps to a list of dictionaries, which contain information about your friends.

So to print your friends list:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends")
for friend in friends['data']:
    print "{0} has id {1}".format(friend['name'].encode('utf-8'), friend['id'])
```

The `.encode('utf-8')` is to properly print out special characters.

Comment: Hello.And if I like the list of people that say "like" of a page not a personal page. Thank you

Comment: How do you get the next page?

Comment: @thekindlyone, it's a URL, so you can click or copy/paste to go to that URL.

Comment: if I requests.get the url, I get empty "data" list instead of list of friends.

Comment: Can you see what happens if you go to that URL from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends)? Are you sure you're passing in the correct access tokens and parameters?

Comment: It returns an empty list. Probably, this now requires that your friends have installed the app, too.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is mislead, as Facebook has shut down `graph` users from getting lists of friends **UNLESS THE FRIENDS HAVE ALSO INSTALLED THE APP**.

See:

```
graph   = facebook.GraphAPI( token )
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends")
if friends['data']:
  for friend in friends['data']:
    print ("{0} has id {1}".format(friend['name'].encode('utf-8'), friend['id']))
else:
  print('NO FRIENDS LIST')
```