# Get the list of friends in facebook

Tags: python, facebook, twitter, html, web-crawler

I am just beginner in Python, so I don't know much about it.

For my research project I have to get the friend list of users(already defined) from Facebook and Twitter by crawling webpages by using Python.

I don't how to start like open account then go to friend, save its webpage, then go to another webpage and do the same.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Facebook at least has a public API for this sort of thing.

Comment: Take a look in the following link https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.

Comment: Try to explain your problem in detail: Do you want to query the list of friends for any facebook user, or just your friends? Do you have their corresponding facebook acoount-names? What du you mean by webpage - if you referr to the timeline of the user, this is not possible, unless they are your friends or the expose their timeline or wall to the public (which is not the case for most people)

Comment: i don't have their corresponding account names.........i just want to query the list of friends......

Comment: Have you tried this code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234237/need-to-list-all-friends-with-facebook-py

Comment: Crawling Twitter webpages is against the terms of service, you should use the official Twitter API as documented via developer.twitter.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Google API.

## https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-and-extract-data-using-python-1839e19d6999

Or use this link for Code

## https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167486/parser-for-facebook-friend-list

You May Can Use this Code of Python For that task get from the upper link...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class FacebookCrawler:
    LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=111'

    def __init__(self, login, password):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

        self.login(login, password)

    def login(self, login, password):
        self.driver.get(self.LOGIN_URL)

        # wait for the login page to load
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))

        self.driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(login)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()

        # wait for the main page to load
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#findFriendsNav")))

    def _get_friends_list(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".friendBrowserNameTitle > a")

    def get_friends(self):
        # navigate to "friends" page
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a#findFriendsNav").click()

        # continuous scroll until no more new friends loaded
        num_of_loaded_friends = len(self._get_friends_list())
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            try:
                self.wait.until(lambda driver: len(self._get_friends_list()) > num_of_loaded_friends)
                num_of_loaded_friends = len(self._get_friends_list())
            except TimeoutException:
                break  # no more friends loaded

        return [friend.text for friend in self._get_friends_list()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler = FacebookCrawler(login='login', password='password')

    for friend in crawler.get_friends():
        print(friend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook's Graph API to fetch friend lists for those who gave permissions to your website **only if Facebook approves your website to access this data** (You need to [request permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review)). I think the chances of getting approval for a personal website is not very high.

Another way of getting this data is that crawling friend lists via an automated code or application. For this to work:

- That person should be your friend on Facebook
- That person's friend list should be open to friends (Some people change the privacy setting to "Only me")
- You need their [Facebook profile URLs](https://unfriendedby.com/#go-to-support-one)

If everything is setup, the crawler goes to profile URLs one by one and visit friend lists to collect data.

Please note that crawling data on Facebook may cause [legal issues](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-to-use-a-crawler-in-order-to-collect-Facebook-public-data) depending on where you live.

Answer (score -2):

You want to start by looking at the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library.