# Friendlist with facebook api

Tags: python, api, facebook-graph-api

i want to return the friend list of a user(not my friends) using the facebook api in python. I want to make a script that downloads all profile pictures of the user and his friends.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234237/need-to-list-all-friends-with-facebook-py and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304272/getting-friendlist-from-facebook-graph-api

Comment: i dont need MY FRIENDS i need other users friends (URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get friends of any user that user must be authenticated through your app. Once he authenticated through your app you can get his friends using below link,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

while authenticating the user with your app you need to get "user_friends" permission from user to access user permission.
Once you any user get authenticated through your app and get userId of friends using above links, then you can use following link to get profile pictures,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/